# How to extract tensors to numpy arrays or lists from a larger pytorch tensor

Tags: python, list, numpy, pytorch, tensor

I have a list of pytorch tensors as shown below:

```
data = [[tensor([0, 0, 0]), tensor([1, 2, 3])],
        [tensor([0, 0, 0]), tensor([4, 5, 6])]]
```

Now this is just a sample data, the actual one is quite large but the structure is similar.

**Question:** I want to extract the `tensor([1, 2, 3])`, `tensor([4, 5, 6])` i.e., the index 1 tensors from `data` to either a numpy array or a list in flattened form.

**Expected Output:**

```
out = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

OR

```
out = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

---

I have tried several ways one including `map` function like:

```
map(lambda x: x[1].numpy(), data)
```

This gives:

```
[array([1, 2, 3]),
 array([4, 5, 6])]
```

And I'm unable to get the desired result with any other method I'm using.

Comment: Are they all the same size though? If yes then that would be much simpler

Comment: Yes the tensors at index 1, which I want to extract are all same sized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, you can just do this.

```
out = np.concatenate(list(map(lambda x: x[1].numpy(), data)))
```

Comment: This very line gives TypeError, but adding list in front of map gives the expected result. I couldn't think of just concatenating the array. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. You might wanna update the answer though:)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a nested list of tensors to a tensor/numpy array with a nested stack:

```py
data = np.stack([np.stack([d for d in d_]) for d_ in data])
```

You can then easily index this, and concatenate the output:

```py
>>> np.concatenate(data[:,1])
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```